# Is it possible to store a JSON file to an ENV variable with dotenv?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-dotenv

I am using Google Drive API with my Rails application. The API is working fine. I have the following client_secret.json file:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "gobirdie-landing-page",
  "private_key_id": "xxxxx",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- xxxxx -----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "xxxxxxx@gobirdie-landing-page.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "xxxxxxxxx",
  "auth_uri": "xxxxxx",
  "token_uri": "xxxxxxx": "xxxxxxxx": "xxxxxxxxx"
}
```

which is called in my controller

```
@session = GoogleDrive::Session.from_service_account_key("client_secret.json")
```

With this configuration no problem, I manage to use the API. However, I would like to store my JSON in the .env file like:

```
CLIENT_SECRET = "{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "gobirdie-landing-page",
  "private_key_id": "xxxxx",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- xxxxx -----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "xxxxxxx@gobirdie-landing-page.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "xxxxxxxxx",
  "auth_uri": "xxxxxx",
  "token_uri": "xxxxxxx": "xxxxxxxx": "xxxxxxxxx"
}"
```

And call it in the controller in this way

```
@session = GoogleDrive::Session.from_service_account_key(ENV['CLIENT_SECRET'])
```

Or in this way

```
@session = GoogleDrive::Session.from_service_account_key(JSON.parse(ENV['CLIENT_SECRET']))
```

But neither methods are working. So my question is : "Is it possible to store JSON file in an ENV variable ?"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Convert the JSON object to string and store it in the ENV

You can use `JSON.dump` to convert JSON object to string

and then in your controller `JSON.parse(ENV['CLIENT_SECRET'])`

**Alternatively**

you can create a `google_session.rb` inside `initializers` folder

```
$google_session = GoogleDrive::Session.from_service_account_key(
   # config goes here
)
```

and in your controller you will have access to `$google_session` global variable

Answer (score 9):

You could just put the item on one line like:

```
VITE_FIREBASE={"apiKey":"slslsls","slsls":"lelsls"}
```

You just have to make sure your **keys have quotes** in them.

and get them (SvelteKit example) like so:

```js
const p = process?.env ? process.env : import.meta.env;

const firebase_config = JSON.parse(p.VITE_FIREBASE);
```

J

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It is possible to store json file in variable. 
However there is one small change needed :

```
\\\"type\\\": \\\"service_account\\\",
```

Do this for every double quote inside the curly braces of json.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the problem remains the same as further explained in my answer below.

Comment: It seems that there are spaces between two ```\```. It shouldn't be like that.

Comment: True, I have deleted all the white spaces but the issue still remains.

Comment: Okay. Sorry then.

Comment: In NodeJs for example you can simply include your JSON as an environment variable value like `SURVEY_OBJ={"IncludeSurveys" : ["abc","wxy","z"]}` and then parse that environment by simply using `let myObj = JSON.parse(process.env.SURVEY_OBJ)`. `echo myObj.IncludeSurveys[1]` should print out `wxy`. So no need to escape quotes or remove spaces.

Comment: @w.PatrickGale your comment deserves to be the answer, IMHO

Comment: @w.PatrickGale offers the best solution. The only catch with Rails env variables is that the JSON object must all be on one line, not simply pasted in as multi-line JSON.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I came up with was base encoding the json object and store it and then decode it upon a request of using it.

Comment: I personally do this as well, avoids having to escape characters as a env var string. I do minify before converting to base64 just to save some chars though.

Answer (score 1):

You have to minify your JSON and change all `\n` to `\\n`:

```
CLIENT_SECRET={"type":"service_account","project_id":"gobirdie-landing-page","private_key_id":"xxxxx","private_key":"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\\nxxxxx\\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\\n","client_email":"xxxxxxx@gobirdie-landing-page.iam.gserviceaccount.com","client_id":"xxxxxxxxx","auth_uri":"xxxxxx","token_uri":"xxxxxxx","xxxxxxxx":"xxxxxxxxx"}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you store the account key as a hash in Rails credentials or DOT ENV, like so

```
google_drive:
  account_key:
    type: service_account,
    project_id: gobirdie-landing-page,
    client_email: ...,
    client_id: ...,
    private_key: "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----...\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
    auth_uri: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth,
    token_uri: https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token,
    auth_provider_x509_cert_url: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs,
    client_x509_cert_url: ...,
    universe_domain: googleapis.com,
```

You can do this to generate a session:

```
session = GoogleDrive::Session.from_service_account_key(
  StringIO.new(JSON.generate(
    # or ENV['google_drive']['account_key']
    Rails.application.credentials.google_drive.account_key
  ))
) 

spreadsheet = session.spreadsheet_by_title("My Spreadsheet")
worksheet = spreadsheet.worksheets.first
```