# Nestjs validate nested object using validationSchema

Tags: validation, nestjs, joi, nestjs-config

```js
a: {
  b: 'c'
}
```

I'm trying to validate it using Joi, inside my module:

```js
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: ['config.env'],
      load: [generalConfig],
      validationSchema: Joi.object({
        a: Joi.object({
          b: Joi.number().min(0).max(2).required(),
        }),
      }),
      validationOptions: {
        allowUnknown: true,
        abortEarly: true,
      },
      cache: false,
    }),
```

I get no error/warning at all. If I change the validationSchema to:

```js
validationSchema: Joi.object({
  b: Joi.number().min(0).max(2).required(),
}),
```

And this is the .env content:

```
a: {
    "b": 1,
}
```

I get the error as always. Any idea?

Comment: how's the content of your 'config.env'? I've never saw one with JSON in it. Maybe yaml fits better

Comment: Added it at the bottom. I'd like to use JSON format, if possible.

Comment: that package uses `dotenv`. Read more about the syntax of the env. file here: https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#rules basically, you can't write it like this (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56277661/i). You could write your own ConfigModule that loads json instead

Comment: I see. Thank you!